# Windows 7 services terminate unexpectedly

Tags: windows-7, windows-services

I'm running Windows 7 Pro 64-bit and recently started to have problems with my sound and network connection. According to the logs, the following four services keep on terminating at random times, but they all terminate at the same time. Reinstalling Windows did not help.

- The TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper service terminated unexpectedly. It has
  done this 10 time(s).
- The Windows Event Log service terminated unexpectedly. It has done
  this 10 time(s).
- The DHCP Client service terminated unexpectedly. It has done this 10
  time(s).
- The Windows Audio service terminated unexpectedly. It has done this
  10 time(s).

Comment: try this hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2799360/en-us

Comment: @alexb, please mark magicandre1981's answer as accepted for this question not to show up on the "answered" list. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since it worked, I'll post it as an answer: [Svchost.exe process that hosts the network location awareness service crashes in Windows 7 or in Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2799360/).

> When you are using a computer that is running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2, the Svchost.exe process that hosts the network location awareness service crashes intermittently.

Open the [Microsoft page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2799360/) and click on "Hotfix Download Available".